# Single User Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I was wondering if there is an accepted solution in the case where I want to write an app (a blog, for example) and I would like for there to be only one user. I've been looking around SO without much luck (mostly running into questions about one User model).

I think using devise or sorcery would be a bit overkill if I would be creating a User model + table just to store one user. Though I also don't want to just store my password in plain text in the source code.

I came across [soff.es](https://github.com/soffes/soff.es) and saw that he was [using the environment](https://github.com/soffes/soff.es/blob/739fd1c0a257ce9d65b96238def1620fbbaeb8c2/config/initializers/constants.rb) to set the username and password. Is this a good solution? Are there other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need some simple auth logic, you can just use [HTTP authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication) and hardcode your username and password.

Comment: Thanks, though it's a shame that it looks the way it does.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too difficult to roll your own authentication which makes it easy to modify later. Ryan Bates has a great screencast building authentication from scratch which will have you up and running in no time.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch (older but free version)

or

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised (updated members only)

Comment: Thanks for sharing but this episode is for subscribers only. I'm not concerned about the complexity of devise or sorcery or rolling my own, but rather the uselessness of keeping track of users where I'll only ever have one. It seems that http auth is probably a good way to go.

Comment: You can always start with http auth and implement a more complex authentication later if needed so if you think http auth is adequate then just go with that. I'm not aware of other alternatives.

Comment: Yep, seems to be like that's how to do it. If I don't need any more than one user then I suppose it's not terrible.